# Simple Slider Styling

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is there a **simple** way to make a slider look like a grid splitter?  (Basically to change the thumb in the slider to a line) I'm trying to create an "overlap" effect to allow a user to expose areas of two similar images.  (This is a follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536757/grid-splitter-overlap/) question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the template fairly easily in Blend. Just add a Slider in Blend, right-click, select Edit Template/Edit Current and then you can see all the elements of the template. Assuming it is enough to update the HorizontalTemplate Grid (used when your Slider is in Horizontal Orientation) You'll want to resize the Grid RowDefinitions and modify HorizontalThumb size, then perhaps change the Fill brush of HorizontalTrackRect and HorizontalDecreaseRect to Transparent. This is a result of such quick update:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App131.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App131"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="SliderStyle1" TargetType="Slider">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SliderBorderThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource SliderBorderThemeThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                        <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="Thumb">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="TopTickBar">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalInlineTickBar">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="BottomTickBar">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="LeftTickBar">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalInlineTickBar">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="RightTickBar">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhiteHorizontal"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlackHorizontal"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhiteVertical"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlackVertical"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate" Background="Transparent">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrackRect" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Fill="Transparent"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Grid.Row="1" Fill="Transparent"/>
                                <TickBar x:Name="TopTickBar" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}" Margin="0,0,0,2" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                <TickBar x:Name="HorizontalInlineTickBar" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <TickBar x:Name="BottomTickBar" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}" Margin="0,2,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalBorder" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb" Background="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" Width="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhiteHorizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlackHorizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid x:Name="VerticalTemplate" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalTrackRect" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalDecreaseRect" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                <TickBar x:Name="LeftTickBar" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,2,0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"/>
                                <TickBar x:Name="VerticalInlineTickBar" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineBackgroundThemeBrush}" Grid.RowSpan="3" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"/>
                                <TickBar x:Name="RightTickBar" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalBorder" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                <Thumb x:Name="VerticalThumb" Background="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}" Height="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" Width="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhiteVertical" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlackVertical" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Slider Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle1}"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thanks (again). I was trying to avoid Blend (and all the clutter), but it seems that's the simplest way to go.

Comment: I understand, I was avoiding Blend for the past few years and would even do these changes in XAML text editor, but once you learn a few basic things about using Blend - it makes it super quick to make design changes without cluttering the code too much.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, unless the default template of that particular control has defined parts which you can override, there is no way to template a control without replacing the entire template.  As noted [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465381.aspx#use_tools_to_work_with_styles_easily), there is tooling to support templating controls.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you do not want to use Blend, but still need to make a slight modification of a control's template, Windows 8 default templates are stored in Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\WinRT\Xaml\Design\Generic.xaml .

When I needed to edit the slider template, I just copy/pasted the default template from the file, into my resource file in my project, and then applied my modifications.